# Pandas: Convert column to dictionary with unique values as keys

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that has the following values where "2" is the column

```
   2
0  0
1  0
2  1
3  1
```

I wanted to make a dictionary out of this like

`{0: 2}, {1: 2}`

What would be the best way to achieve this column to dictionary conversion!?

Comment: `from collections import Counter` probably, do you need separate dictionaries made? order?

Comment: Are you seeking Series.value_counts()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{v: k for k, l in df.iteritems() for v in l}

{0: 2, 1: 2}
```